# How to call JavaScript function from httphandler

Tags: javascript, vb.net, httphandler

My question is simple, how can I call my JavaScript function `runExec()` from my httphandler? This doesn't work

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "myFunction", "runExec();", True)`

It gives me the following error

```
Error   5   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'RegisterStartupScript' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Shared Sub RegisterStartupScript(control As System.Web.UI.Control, type As System.Type, key As String, script As String, addScriptTags As Boolean)': Value of type 'Sample' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.Control'.
    'Public Shared Sub RegisterStartupScript(page As System.Web.UI.Page, type As System.Type, key As String, script As String, addScriptTags As Boolean)': Value of type 'Sample' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.Page'.  C:\Users\Fares\Desktop\RemotePayment 13.10.2014\Sample.ashx 144 17  C:\...\RemotePayment 13.10.2014\
```

Comment: It's the first time I implement an httphandler... Is there any way to do this? @Mohamadshiralizadeh

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are "endpoints". so you can't prompt clients to run a javascript code. [HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are responding to a request, the only think that I can say is that you can write a javascript code into response and then in the client browser it runs. some thing like this:

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext)
...
    context.Response.Write("<script>muFunc();</script>")
...
End Sub
```

this works only when your request is a **text/html** request.